# Configure git in Dockerfile with base of Ubuntu

Tags: git, docker, ubuntu, dockerfile

I understand that the official image for Ubuntu does not have git built-in. So I am creating a Dockerfile using Ubuntu as the base, and then build a new image, like this:

```
# Base image is Ubuntu 18.04
FROM ubuntu:18.04

# Update software repository
RUN apt-get update

# Install git, then remove cache
RUN apt-get install -y git
```

But I don't think this is a sustainable way, for that the Dockerfile will eventually bigger. Meanwhile, it is also very slow and manual. I wonder if there are some ways to install git or other necessary packages faster in a bare bone Ubuntu Docker image. Thanks！

Comment: alpine provides a [git](https://hub.docker.com/r/alpine/git/) image.

Comment: can I use two base images in one Dockerfile?

Comment: You can however I don’t see why you would it this case. If your requirement is to have git then the base image doesn’t really matter. Also, alpine is smaller than ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That right there is the easiest and simplest method for installing packages into a container image. The alternative is to build the packages from source, which involves far more manual configuration!

There are other images which are freely available to pull from registrys (e.g. [dockerhub](https://hub.docker.com)) which may include packages that you already want already in the image. Then all you need to do is pull the image and start working with it.

On speed of builds, remember that specific build instructions (i.e. each line in the Dockerfile) for an image usually only run when:

1. It’s the first time the instruction is being run.
2. Something in the build instruction changes (e.g. you add a new package to the list)
3. The build process is run with the `--no-cache` flag, which always builds the entire image from the scratch.

So once you’ve built the image once, any lines in the Dockerfile that have not changed won’t be executed again. The build process starts from the last unchanged build instruction.

Comment: so is the _build_ commands in docker relatively independent, even they are written sequentially and in a single file?

Comment: Yep - running `docker build` (without the `--no-cache` flag) actually builds an intermediate container image for each build instruction (line in Dockerfile). The next instruction builds another intermediate image based on the previous intermediate image. Check the output of the command - you should see an image hash value for each line of the Dockerfile that it executes...